# Placing data into 'one-per-day' cells in a PHP-generated calendar

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a calendar which I need to populate with data drawn from a MySQL database.

The query response will be an array of rows referring to several dates in a month.  I have to get each row's data into the  that corresponds to its date.  The date info is stored as 'datetime' in MySQL.

The calendar  elements that will hold the data are generated here:

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= $totaldays; $day++) {
    $day_secs = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
    if ($day_secs >= $yesterday) {  
        if ($day_highlight && ($day == $this_day)) {
            print "<td class=\"today\"><span>$day</span><a href=\"CPD_activity_cal_new.php?day=$day&month=$month&year=$year\" class=\"actilink\">Add Activity</a>
            </td>";
        } else {
            print "<td class=\"monthday\"><span>$day</span><a href=\"CPD_activity_cal_new.php?day=$day&month=$month&year=$year\" class=\"actilink\">Add Activity</a></td>";
        }
    } else {
        print "<td class=\"monthday\"><span>$day</span><a href=\"CPD_activity_cal_new.php?day=$day&month=$month&year=$year\" class=\"actilink\">Add Activity</a></td>";
    }
    $day_offset++;

   // start a new row each week // 
    if ($day_offset == 7) {
        $day_offset = 0;
        if ($day < $totaldays) { print "</tr>\n<tr>"; }
    }
}
```

I have three main headaches here:

- can I use the output from
  mysql_fetch_array as-is - in other
  words, can I run a certain way
  through the array in one cell, and
  then restart the loop at the
  correct point a few cells later - or
  must I split it into separate arrays
  for each date (most dates in any
  month will typically be empty) -  and
  if so, how?
- where in the code that    generates
  the day-cells does my code for    this
  belong? I'm particularly    confused
  in this respect by the    separate
  loops for today, pre-today,    and
  post-today
- which form of loop    would be best:
  I've been assuming    while(), but I
  haven't been able    to make it
  work (unsurprisingly, given the confusion above!).

I'ld be very grateful for any advice on this.

Comment: I feel like there is a piece missing from your question. It seems as though you're using a loop to build the table of the calendar, populated with unique links for each day (and formatting), but I'm not sure where your MySQL data comes into the picture. OR, are you asking where in the above would you insert the mysql aspect

Comment: small comment: you can eliminate some redundancy here. Since the only thing that changes in your TDs based on your `if`s is the class, you could just say `$class = 'today';` before your first `if`, then change `$class` inside your `if`s, and after the last `if`, do `print "<td class=\"".$class."\"><span>$day</span><a href=\"CPD_activity_cal_new.php?day=$day&month=$month&year=$year\" class=\"actilink\">Add Activity</a></td>";`

Comment: Thanks Robot Woods - I didn't frame the question clearly: I hope the restatement in an "answer" below is clearer.  And thanks ithcy too - you're right, of course.  I'm under such time pressure currently that right now I just need to make it work - I'll clean it up afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the data looks like and your logic is a little spotty for me to fully understand, but this is basically how I see this working:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DAY('date') AS day FROM table WHERE ... yadda, yadda");

// Reorganize the events into an array keyed by day of the month
$events = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!$events[$row['day']]) $events[$row['day']] = array();
    $events[$row['day']][] = $row;
}

// Build calendar
for ($day = 1; $day <= $totaldays; $day++) {
    // logic for outputting standard calendar format
    if ($events[$day]) {
        foreach ($events[$day] AS $row) {
            // output events
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Michael.  I've moved on a long way with this, but it isn't working yet.

Comment: If I don't remove those square brackets, I have all those duplicate rows in each array.  I can live with that, if the loop works: but it doesn't...

Comment: Alright. Just think about what's happening here: you have two lists that you need to get through, correct? You have a list of days (your calendar) and a list of events. The array that's getting built in the first loop creates a matrix of these two lists: it groups the events together by the day that they occur on. The second loop iterates through every day and checks to see if there are any events for that day. If there are, it loops through the events for that day.

To get more understanding of what the array looks like, can you `var_dump($events)` and post the output somewhere?